# if (Mesh or Brep)'s face is plane,how to get its normal vector

Tags: eyeshot

I want to click an entity's face, and occur its normal vector.It will help me to set a rotating axis.

I follow model1_SelectionChanged in sample:EyeshotDemo,and i can know which face I click.But i don't know what can i do in next step.

Answer (score 1):

You should for face orientation purpose use the `viewportLayout.FindClosestTriangle`.

This will give you one of the triangle that the face is made of (typically the closest to the mouse).

Then from there create a plane specifying the 3 vertex of that triangle which will have a normal direction matching the triangle normal.

Here's a complete working code :

```
// create a basic cube solid
var cube = Solid.CreateBox(10, 10, 10);

// add to the viewport (vp is the ViewportLayout control)
vp.Entities.Add(cube);

// in the vp (ViewportLayout control) mouse click
private void vp_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // get the index of the entity under the cursor
    var index = vp.GetEntityUnderMouseCursor(e.Location);

    // get that item from the entity list as a IFace (since it's a solid)
    var item = vp.Entities[index] as IFace;

    // find the closest triangles
    var triangles = vp.FindClosestTriangle(item, e.Location);

    // get the meshes of that IFace
    var meshes = item.GetPolygonMeshes();

    // in meshes you have all vertex and triangles you need to create a plane
}
```

Comment: var item = model2.GetItemUnderMouseCursor(((MouseEventArgs)e).Location);model2.FindClosestTriangle(item, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location); and it will appear StackOverflowException. why is that?

Comment: @HsinHsien-Huang You did not correctly gather the face. I'll update my example with complete working code.